# How to override an interface function that returns a struct with a mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, struct, interfaces

I have an interface with a public function `foo` that consumes a single `address` parameter and returns a `Point` struct:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IFoo {
    struct Point {
        uint x;
        uint y;
    }
    function foo (address) external view returns (Point memory);
}
```

In my implementation I want to override `foo` with a mapping:

```
contract Foo is IFoo {
    mapping (address => Point) public override foo;
}
```

But I get the compiler error

```
TypeError: Overriding public state variable return types differ.
```

I want to understand how exactly these two types differ. Both consume an `address` and return a `Point`, so what's the problem here? I know this problem is unique to structs because when I try it with a map that returns a value type the compiler doesn't complain:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IFoo {
    function foo (address) external view returns (uint);
}

contract Foo is IFoo {
    mapping (address => uint) public override foo;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is explained by the [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html?highlight=getter#getter-functions).

Basically, the getter for :

```
mapping (address => Point) public override foo;
```

is :

```
// return 2 DISTINCT parameters : uint and uint
function foo(address) public returns (uint, uint) { /**/ }
```

Whereas a struct is really encoded as a tuple such that :

```
function foo(address) public returns (Point) { /**/ }
```

Is represented in the abi as :

```
// Return 1 parameter : tuple of 2 uint
// This code is invalid in solidity, but this is how the abi sees it
function foo(address) public returns ((uint, uint)) { /**/ }
```

So you get `TypeError: Overriding public state variable return types differ.`

I see two ways to get around it, they might not be the best so maybe someone will propose a better solution :

1. Make your interface function `foo` return two distinct `uint`
2. Don't make your mapping public, and write your own getter.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface IFoo {
    struct Point {
        uint x;
        uint y;
    }

    // Method 1 : interface returns distinct parameters
    function foo (address) external view returns(uint, uint);

    // Method 2 : interface is left unchanged
    function bar (address) external view returns (Point memory);

}

contract Foo is IFoo{

    // Method 1 : implementation is left unchanged
    mapping (address => IFoo.Point) public override foo;

    // Method 2 : mapping is not public and not named `bar`
    mapping (address => IFoo.Point) _bar;

    // Method 2 : Write your own getter than returns Point
    function bar(address key) public view override returns (Point memory) {
        return _bar[key];
    }
}
```

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue a while back. This issue cannot be resolved directly. For example, in your code, you are creating a function in the interface for your function `foo`.

Interface:

```
interface IFoo {
   struct Point {
      uint x;
      uint y;
   }
   function foo (address) external view returns (Point memory);
}
```

Contract:

```
mapping (address => Point) public override foo;
```

When discussing interface, your function returns the `Point` struct from a `memory` location. On the other hand, in the contract, your mapping returns the `Point` struct from the `storage` location. This doesn't happen in `uint256` or `address` types, that's why `TypeError: Overriding public state variable return types differ.` error.

If you still want the struct to be returned, create another function that returns the mapping variable.

Contract:

```
mapping (address => Point) private _foo;

function foo(address add) public view override returns (Point memory) {
     return _foo[add];
}
```

In this case, the interface and contract will have `Point memory` as the return type, hence no error.